# parser.parse_args does not recognize arguments in celery task

Tags: python, celery, argparse

I have been Googling this problem most of the morning and find no solution.

Using the following:

parser.add_argument('-t', '--task', dest='task', action='store')

args = parser.parse_args(cmd_args)

When cmd_args contains "['-t my_task']" everything works as I expect.

When cmd_args contains "['--task my_task']" an exception is thrown.

The important part of the error says: "error: unrecognized arguments: --task mytask"

Comment: Try `['--task', 'my_task']` instead. The first case is a little weird, possibly buggy, with the argument being treated as a stack of short options but somehow still associating `my_task` with `-t`.

Comment: Often the simple solutions prove to be correct. Thank you.